# JQuery - add some parameters to a href

Tags: jquery, parameters, playframework, href

I am trying to send some parameters to a method, and I do not know how to convert things to make my java method understand what I want her to know.

I have this html code:

```
<label>info :</label>
@for((k,v)<- map){

@if(k == "humidity") {
                      <button id="hum" value="@k">@k</button> 
                      <button id="@v" class="h_id">@v</button>
                     }else{

                     }

@if(k == "temperature"){
                      <button id="temp" value="@k">@k</button> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                      <button id="@v" class="t_id">@v</button>
                    }else{

                    }

@if(k == "luminosity"){
                      <button id="lum" value="@k">@k</button>
                      <button id="@v" class="l_id">@v</button>
                    }else{

                    }
}
```

In `@k` I get info resource like : `humidity`, `temperature` or `luminosity` and in `@v` I get the `id` of the resource.

And in this script, I want to take all that info and pass it to 
`arduinoChartenv(String id,String id_t,String t_v,String id_h,String h_v,String id_l,String l_l)` :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $(".chart").click(function(){

      var id_t = $(".t_id").attr('id');
      var t_v = $("#temp").val();
      var id_h = $(".h_id").attr('id');
      var h_v = $ ("#hum").val();
      var id_l = $(".l_id").attr('id');
      var l_l = $("#lum").val();

     alert("id temp : "+id_t+" val temp: "+t_v+" id hum : "+id_h+"val hum : "+h_v+"id lum : "+id_l+" val lum : "+l_l);
     //here I get the good values


     window.location.href = "@routes.Application.arduinoChartenv(id,"+id_t+","+t_v+","+id_h+","+h_v+","+id_l+","+l_l+")";
    // here I do not get those values

    });
  });
```

And when I try to print the values that are passed to the method, 
for example :

```
   System.out.println(id_t);
   System.out.println(t_v);
```

I get this in my terminal :

```
+id_t+
+t_v+
```

I tried `jQuery(".????").html();`and a `.innerHTML` ... but with no good result ...

Comment: Have you tried AJAX?

Comment: AJAX it is not my friend. Can't it be done with jQuery ?

Comment: Hehe... AJAX with play is quite simplified actually.

Comment: Do you have some examples ?

Comment: Or you could submit the data as a form to the arduinoChartenv function instead of using JQuery at all

Comment: ok, that is a good idea. I will try it. Thank you.

Comment: And in terms of examples, you can check out the examples provided by Play when you download the files. In particular the project called zentasks has code for AJAX. Some info can also be found here - https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/JavaGuide5

Answer (score 0):

if your code is compiling I assume your arduinoChartenv() method is expecting 7 parameters and it looks something like this..
arduinoChartenv(id,id_t,t_v,id_h,h_v,id_l,l_l)
you are getting wrong results because you are not passing the variables to the method, instead you are passing the variable names as strings. for example in the following line of code

@routes.Application.arduinoChartenv(id,"+id_t+","+t_v+","+id_h+","+h_v+","+id_l+","+l_l+")"

instead of id_t what you are passing is a string +id_t+ . remove the double quote and the + around id_t and it should work.

Comment: nope, it won't work. I do not know why, but it won't see the values of the variables ...